# Pandas: extract data from df to a new df based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df1:

```
Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
1       2     1     1
2       2     0     7
3       4     1     2
```

And then another df2:

```
Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
1       a     b     b
2       a     c     a
3       c     b     c
```

So these two dataframes have the same index and columns. How can I select elements of df1 that only have "c" in df2?

The result should be values from df1 when the condition is met, and 0 otherwise:

```
Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
1       0     0     0
2       0     0     0
3       4     0     2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If first column is index use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = df1.where(df2.eq('c'), 0)
print (df)
        Day1  Day2  Day3
Person                  
1          0     0     0
2          0     0     0
3          4     0     2
```

If first column is not index, one possible idea is select all columns without first and assign back:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:]= df1.iloc[:, 1:].where(df2.iloc[:, 1:].eq('c'), 0)
print (df1)
   Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
0       1     0     0     0
1       2     0     0     0
2       3     4     0     2
```

Or:

```
df = df1.set_index('Person').where(df2.set_index('Person').eq('c'), 0).reset_index()
print (df)
   Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
0       1     0     0     0
1       2     0     0     0
2       3     4     0     2
```

Comment: Great answer. Can the same thing be done by `np.where` also?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Yes, then need `DataFrame` constructor like `df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2.eq('c'), df1, 0), index=df1.index, columns=df1.index)`

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help.

Answer (score 3):

With @jezrael's help, another solution using **[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2.eq('c'), df1, 0), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Person  Day1  Day2  Day3
0       1     0     0     0
1       2     0     0     0
2       3     4     0     2
```